# PDF document signing

Tags: pdf, web-development, image-processing, image-editor

I am working on a project where the user will input data (like name, address and such) in a HTML form.

With the help of PHP, and other tools, I'll use that data to populate a PDF form and database (server-side). Then, provide a copy of the PDF file to the user and the office. It is worth to mention, in the future, will also be Word and other kind of documents (not just PDF).

**I need a plugin (JavaScript, jQuery or whatever) to use with the HTML form, for signing.** This plugin is to digitally sign the document.

**I'd like to be able to attach a signature image and text field to the file.**

Examples are:

- https://www.approveme.me/wp-digital-e-signature
- https://rightsignature.com/
- https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing

For instance, I am looking for a plugin of any kind that will allow users to sign. More specifically, I would like to add an HTML field (`<input type="text" name="signature">`). When the user clicks on it, I'd like the plugin to allow the user to sign (perhaps an "image pad") and then save that image into the PDF form (server-side).

Comment: Your previous asked question isn't' available. You shouldn't refer to it. Please ask the full question here providing enough details. http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information/352#352

Answer (score 2):

Digital Signing PDF or document using just image is not the best option for non-repudiation.  You may use Digital Signature Certificate issued by Certifying Authority in USB Token or Smartcard to Digitally Sign PDF from browser using user's USB Token.

You need to use Browser Extension on the browser side to achieve the same.

The working sample may be referred to at [Web PDF Signing](https://web.signer.digital/)

Disclaimer: I work for CISPL - provider of the Signer.Digital Browser Extension.